# Need jar for WebLogic exporter "https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-monitoring-exporter#Configuration"

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, mojo

Can you please help me to get the jar file for WebLogic exporter "https://github.com/oracle/weblogic-monitoring-exporter#Configuration" . I am new to java packaging and tried many times with maven install command it is giving plugin missing error. Can you please help me with the jar file or steps

Compile with java 7 or above

Error

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ wls-exporter-core ---
Oct 16, 2021 7:34:54 AM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn
WARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
        at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
        at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
        at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.410s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Oct 16 07:34:54 UTC 2021
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project wls-exporter-core: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7852e922]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
[ERROR] roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using WLST scripts and then push the data to cloudwatch using put metric data instead of exporter.